# Must the singular solution of ODE be the envelope of the family of general solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity, singular-solution

1. Must the singular solution (if it exists) of ODE be the envelope of the family of general solutions?
2. If a singular solution exists, is it sure that the C-discriminant method and p-discriminant method will not miss it? If not, how can we find a singular solution in general?

I have read several books and webpages on finding the singular solutions of an ODE. Most of them say that if a singular solution exists, then it is the envelope of the family of general solutions, and therefore can be found using the C-discriminant, p-discriminant, or the simultaneous C-p method. However, as I work on some ODE problems, I find many examples where the singular solution is not an envelope of the family of general solutions. For example,
$$x dy+2y dx=0$$
The general solution is $y=Cx^{-2}$. However, $x=0$ is also a solution to this ODE. Is it called a singular solution or particular solution (since it is not tangent to any integral curve)? In either case, I think I cannot obtain this solution using the C-discriminant method or p-discriminant method. Moreover, to my understanding, $x=0$ is not the envelope of the family of general solutions.

In short, I'd like to know how I can obtain the singular solutions (and particular solutions which are not contained in the general solutions) in general. Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Did you find an answer , because I have same question and could not find anyone to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Let us define a single parameter family of curves $\phi (x,y,C) = 0$, where $C$ is a parameter.

Define a curve *L* to be an envelope of this family of curves, such that:

1. It touches a curve from $\phi$ *at every point*
2. Different curves from $\phi$ *touch L at different points*

If such conditions are satisfied for the curve $L$, then $L$ is indeed the singular solution(s) of your ODE which $\phi$ satisfies.

One can extend this notion to higher dimensions too.

Here, it is a bit different.

We have the ODE $xdy + 2ydx = 0$

$\implies xdy = -2ydx$

In the next step, to separate the variables, we would have to *divide both sides by* $xy$. Since we cannot divide by 0, the solution $xy=0$ is left out while solving the DE.

Here, $x=0$ and $y=0$ are not envelopes because they fail to satisfy both the conditions.

$\underline{\textbf{EDIT:}}$ I am not sure why Shubham Singh has gotten two downvotes, since their claim is completely correct (ignoring their bad Tex). Sure $xy=0$ solution is left out, but you **also need to check if the left out solutions are obtainable from the complete integral/general solution for some constant C** of this DE.

We have the solution $y = \frac{C}{x^2}$, then for $C = 0$, $y = 0$ is obtainable for all x where the original DE is defined in (that is, in $\mathbb{R}$). Hence $y = 0$ is not a singular solution, but a particular solution. Indeed, $y=0$ satisfies $xy' = -2y$

We can also re-write the general solution as $x^2 = \frac{C}{y}$ and again $x = 0$ for $C = 0$ which makes $x = 0$ a particular solution too that satisfies $x = -2yx'$.

Answer (score -2):

Though I don't know answer of your questions 1 &2, you're example require some reconsideration:

No, actually x=0 and y=0 are particular solutions, as if we choose arbitrary constant c=0 then we get y=0 a solution. Also x^2 = A y ,is general solution so from here particular choice of arbitrary constant A ,we get x=0 a particular solution.

Also given differential equation does not have any singular solution.